# Download binary file from server using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Somehow my old post got deleted, anyways, Can someone help me with this - 
I am trying to download binary file from server to client using javascript. Below code works fine but it is using mootools framework but my requirement is to use jQuery. 
I am very new to programming so it will be kind enough if someone helps

```
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.2.4/mootools-yui-compressed.js"> </script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       window.addEvent("domready",function(){
           //Creating a new AJAX request that will request 'input.txt' 
           //from the current directory
           var csvRequest = new Request({
                  url:"input.txt",
                  onSuccess:function(response){
                  $("textResponse").value = response;
               }
           }).send(); //Don't forget to send our request!
        });
        </script>
    </head>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `$.ajax` object to accomplish the same thing. To download same text file use following code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'file.txt'
})
.done(function(data){
    $("#textResponse").value=data;//suppose textResponse is ID of input
})
.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    //handle failure of request
});
```

More information about `$.ajax` can be found [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: Thanks a lot but whenever I am trying to display textResponse ID, I am not able to view the output file. Can you please guide me .

<body>
     <textarea rows="50" cols="90" id="textResponse"></textarea>
 </body>

Answer (score 0):

Just curious: what is wrong with using Mootools?

Anyway, try this:

```
<head>
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'file.txt'
        }).done(function (data) {
            $("#textResponse").val(data);
        })
    });
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: Nothing wrong as such but the organization with whom I am working for is using ajax framework and hence they guided me not to use mootools.

Comment: @SDM, ok. Hope my answer helped you.

Comment: Yes its working but I am having problem in displaying it.I am using below code to display the textResponse but it is not working. Is the below code write? or am I missing something

<body>
  <textarea rows="50" cols="90" id="textResponse"></textarea>
</body>

Comment: @SDM, aha, sorry its `.val()`. Edited my answer.

Comment: Still I am not able to display it. I will brief up now, The textResponse in the ur code contains the data which is fetched but I want that data to be displayed to the end user, how to do that ?

Comment: @SDM, then your problem is somewhere else, because `.val()` works: http://jsfiddle.net/8mxzM/

Comment: @SDM did you see my last comment/fiddle?

Comment: I saw it and it is working fine :) Sorry for not letting u know at the earliest. One more doubt, can we calculate the time taken to download that file and print it? I actually tried with Date().getTime() function but I am not able to figure out the correct way. Can you please throw some light on this?